# How to use Snowflake as ETL / ELT option if you cannot fire multiple SQL statements?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task

we are currently running our first analytics prototype on Snowflake.
The objective is to create a comprehensive analysis result table that can be used for reporting based on ~60 structured raw data tables.
We created all the necessary SQL scripts using the built-in worksheet functionality. In total we wrote around 80 worksheets, each with 5-10 sql statements.
As a next step we would like to automate the execution of these worksheets in a simple, sequential order. However, Tasks and Stored Procedures, both built-in solutions we looked into, fail to execute more than one SQL-statement in a single call.

`Multiple SQL statements in a single API call are not supported; use one API call per statement instead.`

How are you guys handling this? Do we really have to write individual tasks/stored procedures for every single sql statement? In our case this would easily amass to more than 500 of those.

Very much interested in your input, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run multiple statements using tasks when code is wrapped with `BEGIN ... END` block:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK test_task
WAREHOUSE = COMPUTE_WH
AS
BEGIN
  CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test_tab(i INT);

  INSERT INTO test_tab(i) VALUES (1);

  INSERT INTO test_tab(i) SELECT i * 10 FROM test_tab;
END;
```

Call:

```
EXECUTE TASK test_task;

SELECT *
FROM TABLE(information_schema.task_history())
ORDER BY scheduled_time;


SELECT * FROM test_tab;
-- 1
-- 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you're using the wrong tool ;) The worksheets are just not meant for batch processing, if you want to do that you should use the snowsql client:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-use.html

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try!
However, the stored procedure "problem" will remain - correct? So even if I use the SnowSQL client, I still won't be able to create and call a SP with more than 1 SQL statement?

Comment: Even the Snowflake docs have examples with multiple calls, so I'm quite sure you're doing something wrong. Tbh I'm quite sure I did personally execute multicall stored procs from webui even.

Comment: Hi, could you post the links? I was not able to find SPs with multiple SQL calls. Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html has a bunch of examples and I can see some with multiple calls

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't find what I need. Some of the examples in the docs are recursive, but I am looking for an option to truly execute several SQL statement within one stored Procedure call.

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#protecting-privacy and scroll down to the first code example

Comment: Ok, got it now. It is still not quite what we are looking for because you need to reassign `sql_cmd` and execute it when you want to change the content of the statement. I am looking for an option to have several SQL statements concatenated and stored in a variable and then only execute it once.

Comment: i don't think there's an option for that and i don't think there's any real gain in that either.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use worksheet to create stored procedures. You need to use Javascript API (until SQL stored procedures are made available).

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html

Comment: Sorry if this wasn't clear from the original post. We use the Javascript API. The err message was thrown after calling the SP written in Javascript.

Comment: @Stifter did you ever solve this? Having the exact same issue.